# R question. Generate variables followed by number suffix in dataframe

Tags: r

How do I generate a variables as below by just entering a number into a function (in this case 5)?

```
  rank  DATE  OP
1    1 DATE1 OP1
2    2 DATE2 OP2
3    3 DATE3 OP3
4    4 DATE4 OP4
5    5 DATE5 OP5
>
```

Which is the easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste0`:

```
create_df <- function(n){
  data.frame(rank = 1:n, DATE = paste0("DATE", 1:n), OP = paste0("OP", 1:n))
}
create_df(5)
```

Comment: clean solution. For DATE and OP, the `1:5` should be a `1:n` though.

Comment: Thanks. How do I then create the dataframe in the global env inside the function?

Comment: Just store it `df <- create_df(5)`

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `paste0`:

```
df <- cbind(df[1],sapply(names(df)[-1], paste0, 1:nrow(df)))
```

such that

```
> df
  rank  DATE  OP
1    1 DATE1 OP1
2    2 DATE2 OP2
3    3 DATE3 OP3
4    4 DATE4 OP4
5    5 DATE5 OP5
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(rank = 1:5, DATE = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), OP = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```